# Borel - Regular elements

Tags: definition, algebraic-groups

In Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups* (2ed) page 160 a regular element is defined in terms of its semisimple part, “thus $g$ is regular if and only if $g_s$ is regular.”

A unipotent element $g$ has $g_s=1$, and $1$ is not regular. Hence there are no regular unipotent elements according to Borel.

However, “regular unipotent elements” are well studied under the definition “An element $x$ of a linear algebraic group $G$ is called regular if $\dim(C_G(x))$ is smallest possible among all elements of $G$.” as in Malle–Testerman page 115.

- Can people confirm that these definitions contradict each other?
- Is the Malle–Testerman definition more common now?

Humphrey's *Linear Algebraic Groups* carefully avoids talking about regular elements, and only discusses regular semisimple elements where the two definitions agree.

Comment: Springer agrees with Borel. Carter with Malle–Testerman.

Comment: Later Springer uses the Malle-Testerman definition with no comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=206171